# Como fazer for aguardar minhas funções executarem para ele incrementar Java Script

Tags: javascript, front-end

Estou fazendo um código Java Script onde eu preciso que tudo que tenha dentro do for seja executado e depois incremente o for inclusive um setTimeout. No código atual ele executa tudo sem aguardar o setTimeout executar. Segue exemplo de codigo:

```js
var teste = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        console.log(i)

        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("opaopa")
            return
        }, 5000);
    }
}

teste();
```

Neste caso precisaria que o setTimeout executasse depois o for incrimentar.

Comment: Aparentemente vc quer fazer um processo repetidamente. Já procurou ver se não seria mais indicado usar `setInterval` no lugar de `setTimeout`?

Comment: Vou procurar saber sobre o setInterval muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode reescrever essa lógica da seguinte maneira

```js
function teste(i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (i < 10)
    {
      console.log("opaopa");
      console.log(i);
      teste(++i);
    }

    return;
  }, 1000);
}

teste(0);
```

Note que o uso do `for` foi suprimido, `teste` passou a receber o valor inicial do `i`, dentro de teste são feitas as lógicas que vc apresentou, incrementa o `i` e repete o processo até a condição de parada, feita pelo `if`.

PS: alterei os falores de 5000 para 1000 e de 100 para 10, para ser mais rápido verificar a lógica.

Comment: A solução atende para a resolução do meu problema muito obrigado! :)